# Oracle Apex Automation not executing for multiple applications

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, ui-automation, apex-code

I have created 4 automations for one application and these automations work with no issue.  They are set to run every minute and they execute.

When I try to add another automation to a different application, the automation that I create does not execute.  The automation is active and even when I run it as on demand it still doesn't execute.

Can someone tell me what the issue may be?

I've tried adding the same automation, that doesn't work, into the application where the automations work, and it works with no issue.  I'm confused why one application would execute and another wouldn't.

Comment: Anything of interest in the Automation Execution Log? Your question doesn't have enough information to really give you much advice. You might consider asking in the APEX community space https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/apex

Comment: How did you create the automations in the other apps ? When you export and then import an application, all automations are disabled by default - they need to be enabled via shared components > automations or by using the ```APEX_AUTOMATION.ENABLE```API